# Segmentation fault при работе с элементами массива связных списков

Tags: c, null, segmentation-fault, hashmap, linked-list

Имеется массив из связных списков, который состоит из элементов типа node *.
Вот определение:

```
typedef struct node
{
    char word[LENGTH + 1];
    struct node *next;
}
node;

Обьявление массива списков:
const unsigned int N = (26*26);
node *table[N];//пробовал инициализировать ={0}; но table[N] -> next всеравно не равно NULL.
```

И дальше мне нужно создать новый елемент типа node*, сохранить в него строчную переменную, получить хеш-значение переменной с помощью хеш-функции, что бы узнать в какое место масива её вставить, а потом вставить этот новый элемент типа node* в нужное место.

```
FILE *inptr = fopen(dictionary, "r");
    if (inptr == NULL)
    {
        return false;
    }
    int temp;
    char tempword[LENGTH];
    //
    int di = 0;
    while (fscanf(inptr, "%s", tempword) != EOF)
    {
            node *element = malloc(sizeof(node));
            if (element == NULL)
            {
                fclose(inptr);
                return false;
            }
            element -> next = NULL;
            strcpy(element -> word, tempword);
            temp = hash(tempword);
```

И всё идет относительно не плохо, до этого момента.
Во первых, в массив ещё ничего не было сохранено, но **if (table[temp] -> next)** возвращает истину, а мне нужно, что бы последний элемент каждого массива возвращал **NULL**. Но если я пытаюсь выполнить в начале этот код:

```
    for (int s = 0; s < N; s++)
    {
        (table[s]->next) = NULL;
    }
```

то **segmentation fault** выдаёт сразу после него.
Во вторых, при выполнении строки **table[temp] -> next = &(*element);** выдаёт **Segmentation fault**.

```
            if ((table[temp] -> next))
            {
                element -> next = &(*table[temp]);
                table[temp] -> next = &(*element);
            }
            else
            {   
                (table[temp] -> next) = &(*element);
            }
            di++;

    }
            fclose(inptr);
            return true;
}
```

Вопрос:

1. Как будет корректно написать код, что-бы **table[temp]->next == NULL;**
2. Как избежать ошибки сегментации?

Comment: Вы создали массив нулевых указателей, а потом вы не показываете как массив `table` меняете, даёте новые указатели. Покажите больше код. Что вы хотите от этих нулевых указателей? Менять там память?

Comment: Я создал массив элементов типа `node*` в котором **`table[temp]->next`** должен  указывать на NULL. Массив table я должен был менять в последнем показанном блоке кода, но я там менял только ->next.

Comment: Надо было всего лишь изменить `table[temp]` и ошибка сегментации устранена.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вместо сложного :

```
if ((table[temp] -> next))
        {
            element -> next = &(*table[temp]);
            table[temp] -> next = &(*element);
        }
        else
        {   
            (table[temp] -> next) = &(*element);
        }
```

Заменяете голову списка на `element` с хвостом прошлой головы, неважно была голова нулевая или нет.

```
     element -> next = table[temp];
     table[temp] = element;
```